# run bash script from windows pc on linux machine in python

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to create code in Python to connect to a Linux machine from a Windows computer using SSH.
I use Paramiko.

I created a bash script in a Linux machine that the script has several choices (each choice will perform a different action).
For example:

```
Choose one of the options:
1. Hey
Bye
```

If user type 1 something will be printed and if type 2 something else will be printed.

I use the code in Python to execute this script by connecting to the machine in ssh and running the command. I want to enter the bash script and select within the script one of the options.

Can't choose the options, this just prints the script to me on the screen.

```py
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect(IPadd, port=22, username=Username,
            password=Pass, timeout=3)
while True:
    Command = "bash /home/xxx/Desktop/1.sh"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(Command)
    for line in stdout:
        print(line.strip('\n'))
```

Comment: I have no experience with `Paramico` or python on windows, but I think it would be useful to see if the problem is in python or in that `1.sh` script - try calling something else instead (like `date` to get current time or `ls` to list files - and then try those commands with additional parameters (like `ls -1`) to make sure parameter parsing works as you expect) and see if it works then at least you'll know where the bug is.

Comment: Also, showing what's inside `1.sh` might be helpful..

Comment: _If user type 1_ : Why do you design the script as an interactive one, if you want to drive it from your Python program? Wouldn't it make more sense to pass the "choice" number as parameter?